# Abstract class can't be instantiated! in AuthenticationBloc

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc

Screenshot of the AuthenticationBloc

[image: Screenshot of the AuthenticationBloc ...]

how to handle these errors?

This is my AuthenticatationState.

```
part of 'authentication_bloc.dart';

@immutable
abstract class AuthenticationState extends Equatable {
  //
  final AuthenticationStatus status;
  final User user;

  AuthenticationState._({
    this.status = AuthenticationStatus.unknown,
    this.user = User.empty,
  });

  AuthenticationState.unknown() : this._();

  AuthenticationState.authenticated(User user)
      : this._(status: AuthenticationStatus.authentidated, user: user);

  AuthenticationState.unauthenticated()
      : this._(status: AuthenticationStatus.unauthenticated);

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [status, user];
}
```

Comment: Can you show your AuthenticationState?

Comment: Hi, I have added the AuthenticationState.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you want to use a single state, for that u need to remove the **abstract** keyword from state class declaration. U can use

**Note** class is not abstract

```
part of 'authentication_bloc.dart';

@immutable
class AuthenticationState extends Equatable {
  //
  final AuthenticationStatus status;
  final User user;

  AuthenticationState._({
    this.status = AuthenticationStatus.unknown,
    this.user = User.empty,
  });

  AuthenticationState.unknown() : this._();

  AuthenticationState.authenticated(User user)
      : this._(status: AuthenticationStatus.authentidated, user: user);

  AuthenticationState.unauthenticated()
      : this._(status: AuthenticationStatus.unauthenticated);

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [status, user];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `AuthenticationState` is an **abstact class**. So you can't instantied it, which means you can't create an object from it. To fix this omit the **abstract**.
I'm quite familar with [Bloc](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/) and I would suggest you to create a new class for each state and extend from AuthenticationState.

```
@immutable
abstract class AuthenticationState extends Equatable {
  final AuthenticationStatus status;
  final User user;

  AuthenticationState({
    this.status = AuthenticationStatus.unknown,
    this.user = User.empty,
  });

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [status, user];
}

class AuthenticationStateUnknown extends AuthenticationState {
  AuthenticationStateUnknown() : super();
}

class AuthenticationStateAuthenticated extends AuthenticationState {
  AuthenticationStateAuthenticated(User user)
      : super(status: AuthenticationStatus.authenticated, user: user);
}

class AuthenticationStateUnAuthenticated extends AuthenticationState {
  AuthenticationStateUnAuthenticated()
      : super(status: AuthenticationStatus.unAuthenticated);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the class name. You might be using an existed class reserved name in flutter lib. :)